# ASP.NET Core giving me Code 500 on Forbid()

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, web, asp.net-core

I tried to solve this for hours now and I can not find anything. Basicly I have a simple controller which roughly looks like this:

```
[Route("v1/lists")]
public class ListController : Controller
{
    ...

    [HttpPost("{id}/invite")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> PostInvite([FromBody] string inviteSecret, [FromRoute] int id, [FromQuery] string userSecret)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        List list = await context.Lists.SingleOrDefaultAsync(l => l.ID == id);
        if (list == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        User postingUser = await context.Users.SingleOrDefaultAsync(u => u.ID == list.CreationUserID);
        if (postingUser == null || postingUser.Secret != userSecret)
        {
            return Forbid();
        }

        await context.ListInvites.AddAsync(new ListInvite{ListID = id, InviteSecret = inviteSecret});
        await context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return Ok();
    }

    ....
}
```

The thing is: Whenever this method gets called and it exits through `return Forbid();`, Kestrel throws an `InvalidOperationException` afterwards with the message

> No authentication handler is configured to handle the scheme: Automatic

(and of course the server returns a 500). What's strange about it is the fact that I am not doing any authentication whatsoever anywhere, and it does not happen e.g. if the method leaves with `return Ok();`. I'm really lost at this point because if you try to google this problem you get solutions over solutions... for people who **actually do auth** and have a problem with it. I really hope someone over here knows how to resolve this and/or what I could do to find out why this happens.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Like `SignIn`, `SignOut` or `Challenge`, `Forbid` relies on the authentication stack to decide what's the right thing to do to return a "forbidden" response: some authentication handlers like the JWT bearer middleware return a 403 response while others - like the cookie middleware - prefer redirecting the user to an "access denied page".

If you don't have any authentication handler in your pipeline, you can't use this method. Instead, use `return StatusCode(403)`.

Comment: But it worked until today. The bug appeared just today and I certainly did not change anything on my pipeline. Apart from that is 403 (other than 401) not something that should depend on authentication mechanisms imho

Comment: You certainly changed something (otherwise the exception you're seeing wouldn't magically appear). It's worth noting that both the IIS integration helpers (`UseIISIntegration()`) and the WebListener host register a default authentication handler. Did you change that?

Comment: I changed from using the IIS Integration to using Kestrel stand-only while developing, but this project also ran on a Linux AWS Instance through Kestrel stand-only and I can assure you that I definitely got a 403 from it just yesterday.

Comment: And I assure you that `Forbid` can't work if you don't have a handler registered in your pipeline. Feel free to take a look at the source code if you don't trust me.

Comment: @thegentlecat you will finally come down to this line of code: https://github.com/aspnet/HttpAbstractions/blob/b059bcc426ea7593ceeed2df1b6ce14fd3a626ba/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http/Authentication/DefaultAuthenticationManager.cs#L129 ... isn't OSS awesome!

Comment: @MuqeetKhan I looked through the source a long time but neither the git search nor the exception stack trace could help me to find this line