# ASP.NET API Core : Set Result in nested method

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, httpcontext

I have the following base controller class:

```
public class ApiControllerBase : ControllerBase
{
    [ApiExplorerSettings(IgnoreApi = true)]
    protected void IsAccess(int carrierId)
    {
        if (condition)
        {
                ControllerContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 401;
        }
    }
```

and then I call it from my controller, inherited from `ApiControllerBase`:

```
    public IActionResult GetTabletListByGroup(...)
    {
        IsAccess(55555);
```

I want to return `Forbid()` if condition is true. But set `StatusCode` is not enough for it. How to do it correctly?

Answer (score 0):

First, the status code indicated by `Forbid()` is [**403**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47708867/12884742) instead of 401.

Secondly, the `Forbid()` method needs to rely on the `authentication stack` to respond. If you don't have any `authentication` handlers in your pipeline, you can't use Forbid(). Instead, you should use return `StatusCode(403)`.

You can refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44597250/12884742).

I have made a simple demo, you can refer to it:

---

### Update

ApiController:

```
  [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class ApiControllerBase : ControllerBase
    { 
        [ApiExplorerSettings(IgnoreApi = true)]
       protected IActionResult IsAccess(int carrierId)
       {
        if (carrierId >= 1)
        {
            ControllerContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 403;
            return StatusCode(403);
        }
        else
        {
            return Ok();
        }

      }
    }
```

TestBaseController :

```
public class TestBaseController : ApiControllerBase
    {
        public IActionResult GetTabletListByGroup()
        {
             return IsAccess(55555);
        }
    }
```

Here is the test result:
 [image]

Comment: I want to incapsulate all logic in `IsAccess`. Is it possible?

Comment: @OlegSh, Of course. You only need to change the return type of the IsAccess method to `IActionResult`. For the specific content, I have changed it in the answer.